# MediaElement Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagName' of null

Tags: html5-video, mediaelement

I would like to use MediaElement to serve all the videos/formats we have without creating different players.  My first attempt was with an .mwv file with throws the error listed in the Title of this post.  Next I tried an MP4 which seems to work fine.  Then I tried an .flv file which also threw the same error listed in the title.

In Chrome I see "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagName' of null" the console which occurs in mediaelement-and-player.min.js at line 40 but the viewer part of the player doesn't display at all.  In Firefox I see "TypeError: d is null" in the console at the same line number but the viewer part of the player DOES display and it says: "Video format or MIME type is not supported".  The MediaElement documentation indicates that those types are supported but I can't seem to get them to play.

Either I mis-configured the player or I am passing the wrong content-type (I tried several) or this is a bug.  I saw a similar post but the solution posted there was a little vague.  I am going to try different files, formats and mime types to see if I can sort out the issue but I think this is a code problem. Ha anyone else been able to play flv or wmv files with mediaElement?  Was there a trick to making it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I missed a step (or a directive) in the configuration.  The 'tagName' error had to do with the content type I was using and was not defined in Glassfish.  The reason that nothing was playing was that I forgot to list the class  as "mejs-player" in the video tag.

Cleaning up those two things got the player working.